# What's wrong with this .htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I spend a lot of time trying to figure out what's wrong with this .htaccess rewrite with no success. It produces a "500 Internal Server Error" :(

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(([^/]+/)*)gallery/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1gallery/cache/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^.+ cache/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.* index.php/$0 [L]
```

Can anyone see any problem?

Comment: Take a look at Apache's error.log. Chances are the is an answer in there. Quick guesses -- space is missing after `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` and both `^.*` and `^.+` look suspiciously recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your second rule is causing this error. Try to exclude the target you are redirecting to:

```
RewriteCond $0 !^index\.php/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.* index.php/$0 [L]
```